# Atom (vim-mode-plus): Can I auto-exit Insert mode after saving a file?

Tags: atom-editor

I'm using vim-mode-plus and I'd like editor to auto-exit insert mode after saving a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with something like this in `init.coffee`:

```coffee
atom.workspace.observeTextEditors (editor) ->
  editor.getBuffer().onDidSave ->
    editorElement = atom.views.getView(atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor())
    atom.commands.dispatch(editorElement, 'vim-mode-plus:activate-normal-mode')
```

Comment: Thank you very much Dan!

Answer (score -1):

This is actually pretty straightforward:

```
'atom-text-editor.vim-mode-plus.insert-mode':
  'cmd-s': 'vim-mode-plus:activate-normal-mode'
```

Comment: This actually doesn't work; it **overrides** the previous definition of `cmd-s`, so it will go to normal mode, but it will not save the file anymore. So then you have to `cmd-s` twice to save; once to go to normal mode, then again to save the file.